# unknown directive "state" in nginx 1.17.7

Tags: nginx

I am trying to read the office doc of nginx.

There is the following in the upstream module.

```
Syntax: state file;
Default:    —
Context:    upstream
This directive appeared in version 1.9.7.
```

I tried to change the nginx.conf as following.

```
upstream loserver {
      #server localhost:9002 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=1000s weight=2;
      #server localhost:9001 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=1000s weight=100;
      state /usr/local/nginx-1.17.1/conf/state_zwshao.conf;
    }
```

And run the command to `nginx -t` to test the configuration.

I got the following errors

```
unknown directive "state".
```

Anyone know the reason?

Comment: You missed the bit that said "This directive is available as part of our commercial subscription."

Comment: you are right, thx